# How to copy all of partition from a table to another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an oracle 11g production and test environment.Now i would like to copy all of the available partitions from production to test environment . is it possible to do it in a single go or i have to create the partition one by one using the alter table statement.

Comment: Why don't you just take the DDL from prod and create the table in test environment first... then it's just a matter of inserting the rows using CTAS

Comment: I already have the table in test environment. all i need to do is to find a way to copy the partitions from prod to test.

Answer (score 2):

### - Depending on your requirement you can use any of three partitions

- Partition by range

  ```
   CREATE TABLE sales_range 
  (salesman_id  NUMBER(5), 
   sales_date    DATE)
  PARTITION BY RANGE(sales_date) 
  (
  PARTITION sales_jan2000 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('02/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY')),
  PARTITION sales_feb2000 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('03/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY')),
  PARTITION sales_apr2000 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('05/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY'))
  );
  ```
- partition by list

  ```
   CREATE TABLE sales_list
   (salesman_id  NUMBER(5), 
   salesman_name VARCHAR2(30),
   sales_state   VARCHAR2(20),
   PARTITION BY LIST(sales_state)
  (
   PARTITION sales_west VALUES('California', 'Hawaii'),
   PARTITION sales_east VALUES ('New York', 'Virginia', 'Florida')
   );
  ```
- partition by hash( if we not sure about how much data maps into a given range)

  ```
   CREATE TABLE sales_hash
   (salesman_id  NUMBER(5), 
   salesman_name VARCHAR2(30), 
   ) 
   PARTITION BY HASH(salesman_id) 
   PARTITIONS 2 
   STORE IN (ts1, ts2);
  ```
- Subpartitions are also available

Comment: ggreat answer sai. let me give a try on that

Answer (score 1):

I Oracle 11 you can define partionized table in a way that partitions are automatically added when you insert/update any data. Then you don't have to care about it.

DDL is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE T_TABLE
(
  LOG_PROC_ID      NUMBER                       NOT NULL,
....
)
TABLESPACE MY_TABLESPACE 
PARTITION BY RANGE (LOG_PROC_ID) INTERVAL (10000)
```

Comment: this is a very new information to me that partitions will be automatically created. if it inserts automatically then what is the use of an partition.?

Comment: Partitioning has three major reason:
1) Improve performance when Oracle has to scan only part of a big table (or index) instead of entire table or index.
2) Easier Maintenance. It's quick and eady to drop a partition with old unused data instead of doing a selective DELETE
3) You can spread  data of one table into different tablespaces, even store them on different physical disc's

This has nothing to do how a new partition is created. Prior to Oracle 10 an DB-Admin had to create a new partition every first day of month, for example. This task is now automated.